# Como buscar o valor dum elemento duma HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap

Eu tenho um duvida muito estranha, tenho um `HashMap` que tem este dois valores

`ids("pergunta","IdP");`

A `pergunta` é uma *String* e `IdP` é um *Int*,
eu agora para ir buscar o valor do IdP tenho que fazer `int a = ids.get("IdP");` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não, tem que buscar pela *key* - que no caso é `pergunta`.

```
int a = ids.get("pergunta");
```

Comment: `IdP`  é um `Int` , eu fui fazer como você disse e deu o o erro 
_- The method parseInt(String) in the type Integer is not applicable for the arguments 
  (Integer)_

Comment: Sim eu possuo esse tipo de hashmap

Comment: Obrigado @renan ja descobri o meu problema com a tua ajuda, eu estava a usar IdP em vez da pergunta